# Delete everything outside of the results of my query

Tags: sql

All I would like to do is to delete everything that is not caputured by this query:

```
Select Distinct PurchaseOrder.WellID, PurchaseOrder.JobiD, 
PurchaseOrderAccount.AccountCode, PurchaseOrder.PoNumber
From PurchaseOrder Join
PurchaseOrderAccount on PurchaseOrder.ID = PurchaseOrderAccount.PurchaseOrderID
```

I've tried numerious things. Unfortunaltey I get it to work. This is the last thing I tried:

```
Delete
from  PurchaseOrder
Where PurchaseOrder.ID

NOT IN (Select Distinct PurchaseOrder.ID
From PurchaseOrder Join
PurchaseOrderAccount on PurchaseOrder.ID = 
PurchaseOrderAccount.PurchaseOrderID 
)
```

Comment: What database are you using?  What is the problem with your query?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do:

```
Delete from PurchaseOrder
Where not exists (select 1
                  from PurchaseOrderAccount 
                  where PurchaseOrder.ID = PurchaseOrderAccount.PurchaseOrderID 
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon! I thought I tried this, but I guess not!

Comment: Actually it was a good soluton but it turns out Deleting is not going to work with my problem. I am going to have to post another question because I don't have enough space here. Thanks again